# Locale fr on datepicker Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Datepicker of Material UI. Problem is the Datepicker interface : it's in English, and I want a french interface.

So this is my code :

```
<DatePicker floatingLabelText="Data de début" onChange={this.onChangeDateDebut} formatDate={this.formatDate} locale="fr"/>
```

And the interface stays in English :

[image: Datapicker english interface]

How can I change this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Add the ff props to the date picker component

`DateTimeFormat={Intl.DateTimeFormat}  locale='fr'`